# mysql error report from php class reporting 0

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to MySql via a function inside a class. The same could be done easier but this is also a learning experience. The code all works as expected, however if the MySql query fails, the mysqli_error() returns blank, and the mysqli_errno() returns 0. I found the error manually entering the data into mysql and it was a too short column in the db, however I do not understand why the error is not reported by mysqli_error() nor mysql_errno(). Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?php

class FrmAddProduct {

    protected function getDbConnection(){
        return new mysqli("localhost", "root", "****", "test");
    }

    /**
    *all variables are declares and assigned here
    *
    **/
    function commitSignUp (){
        $commitSignUp = "INSERT INTO Login ( `logTitle`,`logFirstName`, `logLastName`,`logLandLine`,) VALUE (\"$this->title\", \"$this->firstName\",\"$this->lastName\", \"$this->landLine\",)";
        if ($this->getDbConnection()->query($commitSignUp)){
            echo "The new product is added.";
            return 1;
        } else {
            echo "Mysql reported this error description: ".mysqli_error($this->getDbConnection()."<br>";
                echo "Mysql reported this error number: ".mysqli_errno($this->getDbConnection());
                return 0;
        }
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQLi OOP-style and procedural-style...  use one or the other, you can't mix. Read more in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are doing here is totally wrong approach. You are creating an instance of connection twice or thrice. And you are expecting the error to be written there.

Change your code in this way.

```
protected function getDbConnection(){
    return mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "****", "test");
}
```

And do this too

```
function commitSignUp (){
      $commitSignUp = "INSERT INTO
                           Login (
                                     `logTitle`,
                                     `logFirstName`,
                                     `logLastName`,
                                     `logLandLine`,
                                   )
                            VALUE (
                                      \"$this->title\",
                                      \"$this->firstName\",
                                      \"$this->lastName\",
                                      \"$this->landLine\",
                       )";

            $conn = $this->getDbConnection();

            if ($conn->query($commitSignUp)) {
                echo "The new product is added.";
                return 1;
            } else {
                echo "Mysql reported this error description: ".mysqli_error($conn."<br>";
                echo "Mysql reported this error number: ".mysqli_errno($conn);
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything from the main issue. It would still do the _exact same thing_ as the OP's current code.

Comment: The only problem with the multi-connection.

Comment: The biggest issue is mixing `new Mysqli` (OOP style) while trying to get the errors with `mysqli_error()` (procedural style). They _can not_ be mixed. _But yes_, you have a very good point regarding keeping the connection as well. I realize that I sounded a but harsh in my first comment. :)

Comment: Thank you to both Vinay and Magnus Eriksson. Vinay, I think the "new" in the getDbConnection should be removed as it is procedural style. Thank you again.